# Thymeleaf - manually processing a template and internationalization?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am able to process a template manually (without Spring Boot), pass in variables and then output the results to PDF using a Thymeleaf template. However, the messages (text) do not get translated and there seems to be little out there on approaching this.

Here is my current code:

```
    ByteOutputStream os = new ByteOutputStream();
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    Random rand = new Random();
    Integer positiveRandInt = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1;

    final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    StandardMessageResolver messageResolver = new StandardMessageResolver();

    messageResolver.getDefaultMessages();

    TenantDTO tenantDTO = operatorService.getOperatorInfo(saleService.getOperatorId(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()));
    DisplayTransactionDetailsDTO receipt = saleService.getsReceiptForPassenger(transactionNumber);
    ReceiptConfig receiptProperties = operatorService.getOperatorProperty();
    Operator operator = operatorService.getOperatorAddress();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/PDF_Receipt_Template/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    templateEngine.setMessageResolver(messageResolver);

    Context ctx = new Context();

    ctx.setVariable("locale", locale);
    ctx.setVariable("lang", "en");

    ctx.setVariable("receipt", receipt);
    ctx.setVariable("receiptItems", receipt.getSalesTransactionItems());
    ctx.setVariable("receiptPayments", receipt.getSalesTransactionPayments());
    ctx.setVariable("receiptPromos", receipt.getSalesTransactionPromos());
    ctx.setVariable("receiptTaxes", receipt.getSalesTransactionTaxSummaries());
    ctx.setVariable("tenant", tenantDTO);
    ctx.setVariable("operator", operator);
    ctx.setVariable("receiptProperties", receiptProperties);

    String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("pdf_template", ctx);

    renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    renderer.finishPDF();

    byte[] pdfAsBytes = os.getBytes();
    os.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(positiveRandInt.toString() + "_receipt.pdf"));
    fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
    fos.close();
```

Is there a way to access Spring Boots messages (Resource Bundle) without Spring? By specifying the location, or resource from TemplateEngine? Then the proper values would be loaded from, say:

- messages.properties
- messages_en.properties
- messages_fr.properties

Comment: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/sayhelloagainextendingthymeleafevenmore5minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageSourceResourceBundle.getBundle from org.springframework.context.support
```

Gets a resource bundle using the specified base name and locale, and the caller's class loader.

@param baseName - the base name of the resource bundle, a fully qualified class name

@param locale - the locale for which a resource bundle is desired

@return a resource bundle for the given base name and locale

```
public static final ResourceBundle getBundle(String baseName,
                                             Locale locale)
```